# pass a function string name to a function, tsc throw an error

Tags: typescript

I want to pass a function string name to a function, 
so I can use it like this:

```
function processArrayObjectPropName<T extends IkeyOfObject>(items: T[], methodName: string = 'toLowerCase'): T[] {
  for (const item of items) {
    const keys: string[] = Object.keys(item);
    let keyCount: number = keys.length;
    while (keyCount--) {
      const key: string = keys[keyCount];
      item[key[methodName]()] = item[key];  //throw an error
    }
  }

  return items;
}
```

But, tsc give me this error:

`Error:(38, 16) TS7015:Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Use the code snippet marked with `Solution`.

---

The error message makes sense, because when you're trying to run `key[methodName]`, it actually calls `String.prototype.operator[]`, with a signature of `readonly [index: number]: string;`.

As `methodName` here is a `string` and not a `number`, as required by its signature, it gives the warning message.

---

What we can do here is to make `methodName` more specific, so TypeScript knows that `key[methodName]` does not return `null` in any case.

```
function processArrayObjectPropName<T extends IkeyOfObject>
    (items: T[], methodName: keyof String = 'toLowerCase'): T[] {
```

Now, TypeScript gives another warning, because number of arguments may be different for different functions.

```
[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'number | (() => string) | ((pos: number) => string) | ((index: number) => number) | ((...strings:...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

---

So we need to make the type specification of `methodName` even more specific, making sure it contains only functions accept 0 parameters;

In this way, we'll have something similar to this, which compiles:

```
// Solution 1
type StringMethodWithZeroParameter = 'toLowerCase' | 'toUpperCase'

function processArrayObjectPropName<T extends IkeyOfObject>
    (items: T[], methodName: StringMethodWithZeroParameter = 'toLowerCase'): T[] {
```

---

Meanwhile there is an alternative to pass in lambda instead of function name, if the signature can be changed.

```
// Solution 2
processArrayObjectPropName(items, String.prototype.toLowerCase);

function processArrayObjectPropName<T extends IkeyOfObject>(items: T[], transformer: (i: string) => string): T[] {
    for (const item of items) {
        const keys: string[] = Object.keys(item);
        let keyCount: number = keys.length;
        while (keyCount--) {
            const key: string = keys[keyCount];
            item[transformer(key)] = item[key]; 
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`key` is a string, `methodName` is also a string, the expression `key[methodName]` would be using a string to index another string which is why you get an error.

I can't quite figure out what you're trying to achieve. Copy all keys of the object to lowercase (or otherwise mangled) versions of those keys perhaps? That might be:

```
  item[(key as any)[methodName]()] = item[key];
```

Casting `key` to the `any` type allows you to subscript the string and therefore get at its methods indirectly.

Comment: I want to do this: `"Foo"['toLowerCase']()`.

Comment: right so you do as the code example I gave and convert the string to `any` (or to an indexable object type if you prefer).